# How to add a program to be indexed by Synapse?

Tags: arch-linux, executable, pacman, intellij

I downloaded the IntelliJ community edition and I'm currently running it by clicking the shell script that is in the folder of IntelliJ

I was wondering how I can make [Synapse](http://mhr3.blogspot.com/2010/11/introducing-synapse-acetylcholine.html) recognize the `idea.sh` file so I can launch it quickly

Answer (score 4):

Make a launcher for `IntelliJ` and `Synapse` should automatically pick it up:

Content of `~/.local/share/applications/intellij.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IntelliJ
Exec=/your/path/to/idea-IC-129.451/bin/idea.sh
Icon=/your/path/to/idea-IC-129.451/bin/idea.png
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;
```

Make sure you enter the right path for `Exec` and `Icon` (the full path for your `idea.sh` and `idea.png` files). Save, double-click it then chose `Mark as trusted` when (if) prompted. Next time you open `Synapse` and type <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>... it should pop up:

[image]